# java: have epoch time, print how long ago in hours/days/weeks time happened

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, epoch

I want to print "1h" or "1d"  or "1y" , ideally all my possible strings only take 3 characters   ie "11h" or "11y"

All my objects have an epoch time and I convert that to a Calendar object

```
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(Locale.getDefault());
    Date trialTime = new Date(time*1000);
    calendar.setTime(mTime);
```

But now I need to know how long ago that time was from now.

```
 long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

If I get the different of the current time and the passed in time, then I'll just be stuck with a low epoch number, if I convert that to calendar object then I'll just have an arbitrarily old year.

My next hunch is to take that difference and determine how long of a time that is, does this use the date or datetime or calendar object for assistance?

any insight appreciated

Comment: Have you checked out Joda time?   Many more useful time/date that your standard java Date and Calendar classes

Comment: @Parasanger yes, but I am not convinced that it is necessary for this, or how that library solves this particular problem

Comment: I was thinking sometime like you get a delta between two dates in tics, then use joda.time.Duration to see how many days, hours etc it was ago.

Comment: @Parasanger ah, I like it

Comment: @Parasanger yes that worked, only took 20 minutes with some conditional logic :) if you want to write it as the answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) has the smarts that you need.

If you take the delta time in tics between your object times you can use [Duration](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) to get number of hours, days, etc.

Comment: The [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) class may also be helpful, in Joda-Time.